# How to redirect to a newly created page using ID and useParams ReactTS?

Tags: react-hooks, react-tsx

For now here is my code

```
import {useState} from 'react'
import { SelectCategory } from './selectCategory';
import { useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function AddPost(props: { addPost: (arg0: string, arg1: string) => void; }) {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
    const [content, setContent] = useState('');
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    let {id} = useParams();
    const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        props.addPost(title, content);
        setTitle('');
        setContent('');
        console.log(id); // return undefined
        navigate(`/posts/${id}`);
    };    

return (
        <div
        className = "create-post">
        <div className = "create-wrapper">
            <div className = "create-intro">
                <h1> Create a new post </h1>
            </div>
            <form onSubmit ={handleSubmit}>
                <SelectCategory></SelectCategory>
                <div className = "create-title">
                <input
                    type = "text"
                    required
                    placeholder="Title"
                    value={title}
                    onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
                />
                </div>
                <div className = "create-content">
                <textarea
                    required
                    placeholder="Write something here..."
                    value={content} 
                    onChange={(e) => setContent(e.target.value)}
                />
                </div>
                <button 
                className = "create-button"
                type = "submit"> Submit
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

For some reasons I don't understand yet the id I get will always return undefined and hence leads the path to redirect to nowhere.

I expect that after I create the new post, useParams will get the ID of the new post and plug it in the path navigate(`/posts/${id}`) but that does not seem to be the case as it always return undefined.